# SpeechRecognition управление рабочим столом с помощью голоса

Tags: c#

подскажите пожалуйста как организовать в одном проекте целый список голосовых команд.

имеется код который распознает одну единственную голосовую команду "стартгугл"- открывает

браузер хром. как прописать код что бы обработчик выполнял серию команд - "стартопера" -

открывает браузер оперу ..
-стартэджэ - браузер эксплорер и т.д.
ссылка на проект https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HJ7srW1PrQDzLfUrjQHPZmbaov_MUUzu/view?usp=sharing

```
namespace xxx
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        static Label l;
        static bool Shutdown = true;
        static void 
sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, 
SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result.Confidence > 
0.1) l.Text = e.Result.Text;
            if (Shutdown)
            {
           System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"); 


        }
    }   


    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        l = label1;

        System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo

("ru-ru");
        SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(ci);
        sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>

(sre_SpeechRecognized);


        Choices numbers = new Choices();
        numbers.Add(new string[] { "стартгугл " });


        GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
        gb.Culture = ci;
        gb.Append(numbers);


        Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);
        sre.LoadGrammar(g);

        sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
    }
}
```

}

у меня все попытки организовать это дело пошли наперекосяк - открывается всё и сразу неважно какая команда

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\\Program Files\C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");
        numbers.Add(new string[] { "стартгугл " });
        numbers1.Add(new string[] { "стартэджэ " });
```

Comment: По крайней мере, отформатируйте код. Выберите в меню Студии пункт Edit > Advanced > Format Document. Или просто нажмите комбинацию клавиш Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D (зависит от выбранных настроек). После чего отредактируйте сообщение, опубликовав отформатированный код.

Answer (score 0):

Я предлагаю использовать гугловский API speech-to-text https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/
После чего банально спавнивать распознанный текст с некими шаблонами-стрингами. И в зависимости от шаблона -- делать некое действие. Довольно простое хоть и большое switch case ветвление будет. Грубо говоря перебор вариантов между распознанным текстом и просто шаблонами текста.

Как альтернатива -- яндексовский API с теми же возможностями.

Можно так же пойти и твоим путем, но могут возникнуть проблемы в стиле "а стоит ли на даном компьютере библиотека для распознавания конкретно даного языка?". Но, допустим, стоит. Все сводится к все той же задаче:

```
switch (recognizedText)
{
   case ("старт хром"):
   case ("старт гугл хром"):
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe");
    break;

   case("start internet explorer"):
   case("старт интернет эксплоурер"):
   case("старт и е"):
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\\Program Files\C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe");
   break;
}
```

и вызывать этот код по ивенту распознавания текста.

Comment: простите но я не догоняю как подвязать эту конструкцию к той что имеется а та что имеется есть рабочая .

Comment: Значит нужно изучать язык с азов, т.к. применение даной конструкции это одна из самых простых задач. Значит недостает знаний о возможностях языка в принципе, и перед тем как это решать нужно взять любой учебник по языку и сначала пройтись по нему, а потом, зная азы, уже пытаться что-то напрограммировать :)

Comment: признаюсь честно я не программист . у меня нет образования соответствующего . занимаюсь этим как любитель от скуки сидя на работе . в общих чертах я понял что мне делать спс за наводку.

Comment: да я, собственно, тоже не программист) Я тоже просто балуюсь)